# What is the adjective for flowers (or other objects) arranged into a vase? Vased?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, is-it-a-word

I want to use the word 'vased' as an adjective before a pronoun of a subject to mean the subject has been arranged into a vase.  It is a flower in this case, but it could be any other object.

The word 'vased' does not appear in any English dictionaries, so I was wondering if there is a different adjective/spelling I should use.